# HTML5 Canvas Make Black Transparent

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, transparent, alpha

I have a large amount of images with a black background, here is one for example:

[image]

Is it possible through Javascript to have to ignore the black (#000000) and have it draw on canvas? to appear like this?

[image]

Basically trying to take the black pixels and make it an alpha channel.

Comment: Not that I know. But you can use ImageMagick to convert all of your images offline: `convert withblack/x.png -transparent black transparent/x.png`

Comment: Yes. It's possible. You can load the image on the canvas then access the image data and overwrite the color you want to alpha out. See here for a guide: https://hmp.is.it/creating-chroma-key-effect-html5-canvas/

Comment: @Amadan Thank you for this! I think this might be my best method since I have hundreds of these small black BG images. It might less intensive on the client to just have them all downloaded as a transparent PNG instead. I see I can put all several hundred of my images in a folder and run `mogrify -transparent black *.png` and voila!

Comment: @Sosa. Bulk pre-processing is best. If you're bulk processing, be sure you don't accidentally convert black parts of your desired tile into transparent.  If you run into the accidental-transparency problem, you can use html5 canvas to flood-fill the black edges with transparency. You can do that once on your dev machine (not every time on the client).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you'll need to run through all the pixels and change the alpha value of all the black pixels.

https://jsfiddle.net/0kuph15a/2/

This code creates a buffer (empty canvas) to draw the original image to. Once thats done, it takes all the pixels of this buffer canvas and then iterates over all the pixels and checks their values. I add up the Red, Blue, and Green values to see if they are less then 10 (just incase some pixels aren't pure black 0), but would visually appear black to the human eye. If it is less then 10 it simply turns the alpha value of that pixel to 0.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('main');

var ctx = document.getElementById('main').getContext('2d');
var tile = new Image();
tile.src = document.getElementById('image').src;
tile.onload = function() {
    draw(tile);
}

function draw(img) {
    var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
    var bufferctx = buffer.getContext('2d');
    bufferctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imageData = bufferctx.getImageData(0,0,buffer.width,  buffer.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
    var removeBlack = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
            if(data[i]+ data[i + 1] + data[i + 2] < 10){ 
                data[i + 3] = 0; // alpha
            }
        } 
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0); 
    }; 
 removeBlack(); 
}
```

You can easily change this line `if(data[i]+ data[i + 1] + data[i + 2] < 10){` to `if(data[i]+ data[i+1] + data[i+2]==0){` if you know for a fact only #000 blacks are used.

Comment: A good start using `getImageData` to fetch and make all black pixels transparent. :-) There could be desired black pixels inside the diamond shape so you might refine your solution to only affect black pixels on the outside of the diamond. Fex: Start top-left at row==0, col==0. Move rightward and clear all black pixels until you reach a non-black pixel.  Restart at row==1, col==0. Move rightward and clear all black pixels until you reach a non-black pixel ... and so on. Repeat, starting at all 4 corners.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish that using blend modes.

Change the context `globalCompositeOperation` to `screen`, and you can get that result. Here's an example:

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");


var image = new Image();
image.src = "https://images.blogthings.com/thecolorfulpatterntest/pattern-4.png";

image.onload = function() {
  context.drawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  var blackImage = new Image();
  blackImage.src="http://www.printmag.com/wp-content/uploads/Sillitoe-black-white.gif";
  blackImage.onload = function(){
    context.globalCompositeOperation = "screen";
    context.drawImage(blackImage, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }

};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="300" height="250"></canvas>

<hr/>
<h1>Images used:</h1>

<img src="https://images.blogthings.com/thecolorfulpatterntest/pattern-4.png"/>

<img src="http://www.printmag.com/wp-content/uploads/Sillitoe-black-white.gif"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for responding! I tried it out on my main code but it didn't seem to work. Here's an example [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kuph15a/).

Comment: The canvas is with black background. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0kuph15a/1/)

Comment: I know that it fills with black by default but I want that true transparency

Comment: @Filipe I have an issue with the given solution. The drawing color getting very lighter in the final output, not the original color. See the example in https://jsfiddle.net/eonjs623/2/ can you please help me to get the original drawing color.

Answer (score 0):

How about saving the picture as an .svg file...from there you can change all colors and other settings

Answer (score 0):

Felipe's answer addressed my issue. Alpha pixel manipulation does *not* work
(eg, setting every 4th pixel to 0) for preserving alphatransparency with multiple images added into the *same* context at the same time.

eg:

```
this.ctx1.putImageData(output, 0, 0); // without setting the context's globalCompositeOperation, this image is written over by the next putImage operation
this.ctx1.putImageData(output, 20, 0);
```

Go here to review the blending options. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/globalCompositeOperation