# How can I make 100% black pixels in a Video Transparent without using mix-blend-mode: screen within HTML

Tags: css, html, video, transparent

I have found a really interesting piece of code which turns pure black pixels within an image transparent and I was wondering whether this is possible to do with a video? I have videos with black backgrounds which I preferably need to be truly transparent rather than using a screen blend mode as it dulls the overall video and causes issues when layer with other videos.

I am aiming to create something like this: http://patatap.com/ but with a 3D aesthetic rather than 2D!

Link to the original question: [HTML5 Canvas Make Black Transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643175/html5-canvas-make-black-transparent)

The code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('main');

var ctx = document.getElementById('main').getContext('2d');
var tile = new Image();
tile.src = document.getElementById('image').src;
tile.onload = function() {
    draw(tile);
}

function draw(img) {
    var buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
    var bufferctx = buffer.getContext('2d');
    bufferctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var imageData = bufferctx.getImageData(0,0,buffer.width,  buffer.height);
    var data = imageData.data;
    var removeBlack = function() {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i += 4) {
            if(data[i]+ data[i + 1] + data[i + 2] < 10){ 
                data[i + 3] = 0; // alpha
            }
        }
        ctx.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);
    };
 removeBlack();
}
```

I am new to coding and hope that this is possible to do! I would want to apply this technique to all my videos within my file however im not sure if this would be incredibly impractical!

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head> 
        <title></title>

        <style type="text/css">

            #backplate {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: -5;
            }

            #twinkle {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: -3;
                mix-blend-mode: screen;
            }

            #skel-walk {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: -1;
                mix-blend-mode: screen;
            }

            #clap-test {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: 0;
                mix-blend-mode: screen;
            }

            #chord-1 {
                position: absolute;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                min-height: 100%;
                min-width: 100%;
                z-index: -2;
                mix-blend-mode: screen;
            }       


        </style>



    </head>
    <body>



        <!--BACKPLATE-->


        <img id="backplate" src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Back_Plate00000.png">  


        <!--SKEL-WALK-->

        <!--<img id="skel" src="Music_Animation/Skel_Sheet/Skel_Sheet">-->



        <video id="skel-walk" preload="auto" autoplay="true" loop="loop" muted="muted">
            <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_Skeleton_Walk_TTP.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Video not supported

        </video>  


        <!--CLAP-TEST-->


        <video id="clap-test" preload="auto">
            <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Clap.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Video not supported


        </video>



        <!--CHORD-2-->


        <video id="chord-1" preload="auto">
            <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Chord_2.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Video not supported


        </video>


        <!--TWINKLE-->


        <video id="twinkle" preload="auto">
            <source src="Music_Animation/Test_Files/Lighting_FX_Twinkle.mp4" type="video/mp4">
            Video not supported

        </video>



            <script>
                var video1 = document.getElementById("clap-test");
                var video2 = document.getElementById("chord-1");
                var video3 = document.getElementById("twinkle");
                document.onkeypress = function(e) {
                    if ((e || window.event).keyCode == "83") {
                        video1.currentTime = 0, video1.play();
                    }
                    if ((e || window.event).keyCode == "65") {
                        video2.currentTime = 0, video2.play();
                    }
                    if ((e || window.event).keyCode == "65") {
                        video3.currentTime = 0, video3.play();
                    }
                };
            </script>



    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: hint: you might want to pipe it through a glsl shader

Comment: alternatively you'd just want to use a webm with transparency. https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2013/07/Alpha-transparency-in-Chrome-video (supported since 2013)

Comment: example: https://simpl.info/videoalpha/

Comment: @GottZ Thanks for this i'll look into these!!!