# Overlay two base64 image url and save them as single image in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, base64

I have a whiteboard option during a video call in my web application built in angularjs (1.x). Users can draw above the video in a canvas element.  I need to take a screenshot of the current video position and drawing on the canvas.  I am able to get the video frame as base64 URL(second image) and canvas drawing as base64 URL(third image) separately. But I need to get it as a combined single image in base64 URL like the first image.

[image: video image with drawing taken from mobile app]

[image: Video image]

[image: Drawing image]

HTML

```
<img id="img1">
<img id="img2">
<canvas id="mergedImage" width="382" height="510"></canvas>
```

JS

```
var drawingImg1 = document.getElementById('img1');
drawingImg1.setAttribute('src', img1);
var drawingImg2 = document.getElementById('img2');
drawingImg2.setAttribute('src', img2);

var c = document.getElementById('mergedImage');
var width = 382;
var height = 510;
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var imageObj2 = new Image();
imageObj2.onload = function (){
    ctx.drawImage(imageObj2, 0, 0, width, height);
    var imageObj1 = new Image();
    imageObj1.onload = function (){
        imageObj1.style.objectFit = "cover";
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj1, 0, 0,width, height);
    };
    imageObj1.src = img2;
};
imageObj2.src = img1;
```

I tried the above code and it gives the output as video frame image only not the drawing included.
I want the output as the first image.  Please, someone, guide me to do this.

- [I have created a jsfiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/epdtjL5s/1/)

Comment: firstly, you'll want to set the background then add the foreground - you're doing it the other way around at the moment

Comment: once you do it in the right order ... see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35643175/html5-canvas-make-black-transparent

Comment: Thanks a lot, @JaromandaX. It worked.

Comment: @JaromandaX- I have an issue in the given solution.  The drawing color getting very lighter in the final output, not the original color. See the example in https://jsfiddle.net/eonjs623/1/

Answer (score 0):

The following solution worked for me to overlap 2 images and got a single image in a canvas.
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35643333/1866157)